# How to separate double hover on button?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I wonder if there is a similar thread, but I couldn't find it.

There are two hover events on my button. What I want to achieve is: when I hover everything except `close`, whole button (except close) turns to gray and when I hover `close` it (only) becomes black.

As you can notice, when I hover on `close` (red), two hovers appears take place. Button becomes gray and `close` black. I need to separate these two hovers.

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/a3Lkoe9p/)

The code:

HTML

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="btn">
    <span class="text">Description 1</span>
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn">
    <span class="text">Description 2</span>
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgba(189, 195, 199, 1)
}

.close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.close:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element within the close button to hide the black background on the parent hover:

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgba(189, 195, 199, 1)
}

.close {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.close:hover {
  background: black;
}
.close:hover::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="btn">
    <span class="text">Description 1</span>
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="btn">
    <span class="text">Description 2</span>
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```